# In django models, how to make all table names not have the app label?

Tags: database, django, django-models

I have a database that was already being used by other applications before i began writing a web interface with django for it. The table names follow simple naming standards, so the django model Customer should map to the table "customer" in the db. At the same time I'm adding new tables/models. Since I find it cumbersome to use app_customer every time i have to write a query (django's ORM is definitely not enough for them) in the other applications and I don't want to rename the existing tables, what is the best way to make all models in my django app use tables without applabel_, besides adding a Meta class with db_table= to each model?

Is there any reason why I shouldn't do this? I have only one web app that needs to access this db, everything else doesn't use django models.

Comment: And the reason for not using the Meta class is ...? It sounds like you are saying, "I want to drive a car, but I don't want to use my hands."

Comment: The reason is, django names tables this way automatically, and I should be able to disable it and name it my way automatically. I don't even want esoteric names, just the name the class, like django does, except for the applabel_ bit. Adding Meta: db_table = className.lower() to each class seems stupid and repetitive.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `Meta` class in your model class and within it specified your table name as `db_table`.

In the [Django Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#db-table):

```
class Meta:
    db_table = 'my_author_table'
```

Answer (score 1):

This **might** work (I haven't tested it)

```
class CustomModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._meta.db_table = self.__class_.__name__.lower()
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then you inherit all your models from CustomModel.
Although I'm not sure it's worth the trouble, just to avoid specifying it in Meta.

Comment: Current project has 160+ model tables, it would be worth it.  It'd be great if there was documentation on whether it will continue to be supported.

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen early enough in my experiments to affect the true table name.  The technique involving a metaclass that runs earlier does seem to work however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382414/450917