# Django table naming convention. Can I change its behavior?

Tags: django, django-models

When Django creates tables it give them names of form app_class.  I'm in the position of retrofitting a different (but basically similar in content) database to a Django installation.  My tables name are not prepended with app_.

I could recreate my database and its tables accordingly but I'd like to see if Django has the flexibility to modify how it handles table names.

That is, I have a table coi_fs - I'd like to see if I can change the Django installation such that it will refer not to app_coi_fs but simply coi_fs?

Comment: have a look here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names

Answer (score 8):

If you already have a database I would recommend using the database introspection option. This will create the models needed to use your current database as is.

```
$ django-admin.py inspectdb > models.py
```

To answer your original question though, from the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names), you can use the db_table meta property.

## models.py

```
class DjangoSite(models.Model):
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'site'
```

Comment: The inspectdb option actually creates the models with the db_table Meta field!

Comment: That's useful information Victor (which I already had) but it doesn't solve this particular problem.  In the end, I solved the problem by going back to my CREATE DATABASE script and prepended table names with app_.  I was hoping for a better solution but this will do.  So I can't mark you answer solved but I can give it a +1.

Comment: the class Meta:
db_table = u'table_name'


That solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can do it in Django, just change Model's metaclass:

```
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class ModelMetaClass(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        new_class._meta.db_table = some_awesome_logic_implemented_by_you()

        return new_class
```

and then in the Model:

```
class DjangoSite(models.Model, metaclass=ModelMetaClass):
    # __metaclass__ = ModelMetaClass  # Python 2.x

    class Meta:
        pass
```

and you are done!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to universally rename all tables, edit django source. This seems dangerous but if you explicitly want to change the Django installation than have at it. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/options.py

## old options.py

```
self.db_table = "%s_%s" % (self.app_label, self.model_name)
```

## new options.py

```
self.db_table = self.model_name
```