# Django - no such table - custom sql

Tags: django, operationalerror

I don't understand why Django can access my table just fine when I use its built-in query functions, ie. `Perk.objects.all()`, but the moment I try to use custom sql, it says there is no such table.

```
def sql(self):
    queryset = Perk.objects.all() # works fine
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM perk")  # Fails. No such table: perk.
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default django naming convention for tables is "appname_classname". You can read about changing the defaults here:

[Django table naming convention. Can I change its behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944016/django-table-naming-convention-can-i-change-its-behavior)

Or look in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/

And you might peek in your database to see what the table is actually called.